# Foundation 5 : What's the best way to modify the default values in scss files

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'd like to know what the best way to modify the default values in the scss files. If I mofidy in the scss files, as soon as i do `foundation update` it will reset all the modified values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create foundation-settings.scss file with your settings for project.

And include this file before Zurb foundation:

```
@import foundation-settings;
@import foundation;
```